# Xcode Scene Editor - How do you display entities list?

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit, skscene

I cannot find a way to display the entities list on xcode as shown in this picture from Apple website:
[image]

Comment: Click on any `.dae`file in your project pane and it will enlist the entities just like in image above.

Comment: I don't have any .dae files. I thought this was the scene editor. isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture you're looking at is the SceneKit editor for 3D assets.

Judging by your question tags, you're looking for information about the SpriteKit scene editor? That editor does not have an entities list like the SceneKit editor.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I wish there was something like that for Scene as well

Comment: I imagine [Apple would be interested in such feedback](http://bugreport.apple.com).